How to globally disable webpack prefetch magic comment
I have few modules lazy loaded and prefetched using the magic comment: /* webpackChunkName: ""*, WebpackPrefetch:true"
but I want to disable/enable webpack prefetch based on webpack config, as I have different build scenarios, and some of them shouldn't have prefetch logic (i.e. adding the resource hint ).
I tried using LimitChunkCountPlugin but it doesn't solve the problem.
